# How to get local storage data and set to default redirecto route in angular 7?

Tags: angular

```
    import { NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { AuthGuardService } from './../providers';
    import { AdminComponent } from './../admin/admin.component';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './../admin/dashboard/dashboard.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './../admin/login/login.component';

    import { CreateivrComponent } from '../share/createivr/createivr.component';
    import { CalllogComponent } from '../share/calllog/calllog.component';   
    //  canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    var roles: [];
    var starting_url='users';
    roles = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('adminroles')); 
    if(roles!=null){
     if(roles.includes('View_Users_List')){
         starting_url="users";
     }
     else if(roles.includes('View_Request_List')){
         starting_url="request";
     }
     else if(roles.includes('View_Billing_List')){
         starting_url="billing";
     }

     else if(roles.includes('View_Android_List')){
         starting_url="android";
     }
     else{
         starting_url="users";
     }


    }




    const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: '', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: starting_url, pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'users', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' },
            { path: 'request', loadChildren: './request/request.module#RequestModule' },
            { path: 'android', loadChildren: './android/companylist.module#CompanylistModule' },
            { path: 'billing', loadChildren: './billing/billing.module#BillingModule' },
            { path: 'subadmin', loadChildren: './subadmin/subadmin.module#SubadminModule' },
            { path: 'createivr', component: CreateivrComponent },
            { path: 'calllog/:id', component: CalllogComponent },
            { path: 'createivr/:userid', component: CreateivrComponent },
            { path: 'editivr/:id/:userid', component: CreateivrComponent },

        ]
    }
    ];

    @NgModule({
    exports: [RouterModule],
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
    })

    export class AdminRouting { }
```

Is there any way? I have roles in localstorage. So I want to get localstorage value and set to default routes value in angular7, how to do this pleas help anyone? I'm new to angular and nodejs so please help anyone, please see above is my angular router file.

Comment: How do you add roles to localStorage and how localStorage string looks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The router file is used to setup the possible routes. I would recommend putting the actual default routing inside of the ngOnInit function of you Login Component. So inside of that function you would pull the role value from local storage and then navigate to a route depending on the value. Next, change the blank path to redirect to the login component. Then, add a path name for AdminComponent. This can be anything that works for you but I used 'admin' in the example below.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{
  path: 'admin', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'users', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' },
        { path: 'request', loadChildren: './request/request.module#RequestModule' },
        { path: 'android', loadChildren: './android/companylist.module#CompanylistModule' },
        { path: 'billing', loadChildren: './billing/billing.module#BillingModule' },
        { path: 'subadmin', loadChildren: './subadmin/subadmin.module#SubadminModule' },
        { path: 'createivr', component: CreateivrComponent },
        { path: 'calllog/:id', component: CalllogComponent },
        { path: 'createivr/:userid', component: CreateivrComponent },
        { path: 'editivr/:id/:userid', component: CreateivrComponent },

    ]
}];
```

So now when the user navigates to your site with a blank path they will be redirected to the login component. The login component will check the local storage value and, if they have access, redirect to the appropriate component.